# Overloading a returned class (eg DomParser's Document in xmlpp)

Tags: c++, libxml2, gtkmm

I'm getting back into C++ after a decade's hiatus and found a lot has been going on while I've been away and I think I'm missing something fundamental about modern frameworks.

I have a document. It's my document. It is an xml document but with extra features so, from a design point of view, it should be derived from xmlpp::Document.

However, it is loaded from a source which means going through xmlpp::DomParser which returns a basic xmlpp::Document object - not what I want.

A basic cast isn't going to do it because of the extra data my class contains.
I don't want to merely store the document as a property of my own class because there are many circumstances where I'm dealing with it directly.

I could, as a worst-case scenario, import the root node into my own object but that seems like overkill and I've a feeling I'm missing something fundamental here. Is there something in the framework that I'm overlooking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a decorator, or simply overload the copy (and move, if `c++11`) assignment operators and constructors, so your object will be created from the `xmlpp::Document` you get, as a subclass of this type.

Comment: Thanks but once again, that's copying the results. In this particular case, I will probably do that and think of the parser's document as a document fragment (subsequent fragments have to be processed and merged anyway) but I keep getting glimpses of a more elegant solution.

Maybe I need to dissect the source of GtkBuilder::get_widget_derived.

I'm trying to learn the framework properly and not become one of those developers who take a new concept, completely miss the point and try to force it to behave like what they're used to.

Comment: AFAIK, it's the best way to do this. With C++11 you can optimize this with move semantics, and for previous version, RVO deletes this copy. Your object is created from an `xmlpp::Document` and you'll have at most maybe one copy of your data, which will be the same as using another solution...

Comment: Beside, you should not worry about this little copy ellision until your program works and you have identified this part as a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing a lot of research into this and the answer falls into two parts.

I was correct in that, unlike many other C++ platforms, there is an easy way to overload an existing Gtkmm class.

The Gtk philosophy is that the actual object is the GObject handle and the C++ wrapper is just one of many (Python, Perl etc). Therefore, even the properties are set in the handle via Glib::Object::set_property (name, T& value) and Glib::Object::get_property (name, T&value). In effect, the GObject is the real "class".

Since both the derived class and the original share a common GObject format (in this case a libxml2, _xmlDoc object), the standard GtkObject's wrap function should be able to transfer ownership thus:

```
GtkObject  *pObj = pGtkObjectBasedClass->c_obj ();
pMyObjectBasedClass->wrap (pObj);    // Automatically increases ref count of object
delete pGtkObjectBasedClass;
```

That is the generic way. In the case of xmlpp, there is no "wrap" function implemented and it is derived from Noncopyable. However, in the newest update, the constructor which takes an existing object or document as a parameter is now public and no longer private so transferring should now be possible. Non-standard but it should achieve the same effect.

Comment: GtkObject would be a C object (actually GtkObject doesn't exist in GTK+ 3. GObject is probably what you mean). So it doesn't have a wrap() method.

You certainly can't easily just steal away the underlying GObject from gtkmm instances. Anyway, libml doesn't use GObject so libxml++ doesn't use the same wrapping system as gtkmm.

Comment: You're right. I had just discovered this so my terminology was a little erratic.

Comment: Additional: much coding later, I've discovered that it's far better (and easier in the long run) to go straight down to the xmllib2 functions and write my own wrappers. I wish developers would learn the difference between a wrapper and a framework.

Answer (score 0):

No, the code instantiates an xmlpp::Document, so you can't do this with libxml++ without changing the actual code of libxml++.

I don't really see the benefit of having a MyDocument that's derived from xmlpp::Document anyway. You wouldn't be trying to override any behaviour of the xmlpp::Document or trying to achieve any kind of polymorphism and you wouldn't be writing less code. In fact, just using the xmlpp::Document as a member variable of your Document class would hide the lower-level XML API from users of your Document class.